# Selected Spam flag in Triage, but the audit said I clicked "Looks OK"? (with proof)

Tags: support, bug, status-review, review-audits, triage

**Update**

I tested it today and the same issue occurred.

The question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/29702035

What happened:

[image]

---

I encountered [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/29693259). It's obviously for a spam post.

I'm pretty sure I clicked "Flag" and "Spam".

Maybe I flagged using the "Flag" button below the question instead of the menu on the right.

Can anyone with enough permission / ways can **verify** what I clicked / selected?

Comment: It just says that you selected "Looks OK": https://i.imgur.com/9eQn1ys.png I have not way to check if you flagged it or not, however.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks. I thought moderators would have access to that information. I will use the menu on the right for flagging from now on anyway, no problem.

Comment: I've seen bug reports for normal reviews where flagging stuff would not complete the review. Maybe that bug is related to this one.

Comment: @HardcoreGamer I'm a regular user, not a diamond mod.

Comment: @rene In my case, the flagging completed the review but counted as "Looks OK". Hotfix gone wrong maybe? Thanks for the info. Only moderators would know then.

Comment: You can check what you flagged at https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/6670491 @HardcoreGamer - doesn't appear you ended up actually flagging that post

Comment: @JonClements Do audit posts included in this flag history?

Comment: Not if the flag would effectively be a no-op - so in this case the post was already spam deleted a month ago and had you chosen flag/spam your audit outcome would say "Flag" instead of "Looks OK" (even though it wouldn't count as an actual proper flag in your history).In summary - there's no record of you flagging it... whether that's because you just didn't, or you did but there was a glitch in the matrix... seems like it's likely the former though...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for your time and the clarification. I must have had a brain fart then. You can rest this case. Yet again, Thanks.

Comment: @JonClements I updated this post with a recording that replicated the issue, please check. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that definitely looks like a bug. It would probably be good for you to post this as an answer to [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/271271).

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for the link. This bug is now added as [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369241/1060448). I'm glad I did not lose my sanity.

Comment: @HardcoreGamer thanks for taking the time to do that... yeah... something appears to have been borked in the review updates :p